# Efficiently deleting rows with character variables in R

Tags: r, coding-efficiency, rowdeleting

I would like to delete a few rows that have a specific character variable. I can do it but it is not efficient.  The below code works but I would like a more efficient way.

```
Stuff2<-Stuff1[!Stuff1$State.Code=="PR",]
Stuff2<-Stuff2[!Stuff2$State.Code=="HI",]
Stuff2<-Stuff2[!Stuff2$State.Code=="AK",]
```

How do I create one line of code that removes all observations with PR, HI and AK?  I see many examples of numeric values but none for character.

Comment: Take a look at `filter` function from `dplyr`.

Comment: maybe something like `Stuff2<-Stuff1[!Stuff1$State.Code %in% c("PR", "HI","AK"),]` ?

Comment: That worked  jacky_learns_to_code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
Stuff2 %>%
    filter(!State.Code %in% c("PR", "HI", "AK"))
# you remove if state.code is not in the character vector provided.
```

And with base R:

```
subset(Stuff2, !State.Code %in% c("PR", "HI", "AK"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression and base R:

```
Stuff2[grepl("[^(PR|HI|AK)]",Stuff2$State.Code),]
```